# Leave One Out Scores 100%, what am I missing here?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, naivebayes

I am trying to perform Leave-one-out CV on my articles but when I run the procedure I get 100% accuracy and I cannot figure out what am I missing. This is my code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, LeaveOneOut
from scipy.stats import sem
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

bunch = load_files('corpus', shuffle = False)

X = bunch.data
y = bunch.target

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)

estimator = MultinomialNB().fit(X_tfidf, y)
cv = LeaveOneOut(26)
scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X_tfidf, y, cv = cv)
print scores
print ("Mean score: {0:.3f} (+/-{1:.3f})").format(np.mean(scores), sem(scores))
```

And I get identical classification as input data, which is a bit strange. My results:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
Mean score: 0.577 (+/-0.099)
```

And my input data classification:

```
([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I do not understand where my LOO CV fails. :S

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your accuracy score from the LOOCV 0.577 as you printed from the last line?

The [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) function returns an array of scores (by default accuracy) from each fold of CV. The array `scores` you printed is accuracy score rather than prediction.

Comment: Hey, thats what puzzles me, accuracy generated is 0.577 but prediction output is same as Gold standard, so all of the articles are classified correctly according to array output. Maybe I do not understand something.

Comment: The array you printed does not stand for the labels but the accuracies.
Each element in the array is the accuracy score for each iteration of LOOCV. You should take the mean of those values to compute the overall prediction accuracy which is 0.577